# Why are these circuits not producing the expected output?

Tags: circuit-construction, quantum-fourier-transform, cirq, quirk

This circuit was created on the Quirk platform. I'm trying to implement a basic case of phase estimation. For some reason, I'm getting this strange result.

[image]

When the Inverse QFT is broken down, it seems to yield the expected answer:

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening. I tried playing around with the endian-ness of the qubits, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

The endian-ness of the qubits is the answer. Both QFT and phase estimation rely on certain endianness of the register, and the representations used in the controlled-unitary part has to match the endianness used in the QFT part (and in the answer). This circuit produces the expected outcome with the inverse QFT block:

[image]

Comment: But why am I getting this result? I am trying to implement the phase estimation algorithm, and this doesn't seem to be the expected outcome of this circuit.

Comment: Additionally, when I try to flip the circuit to correct for the endian-ness on the preprogrammed inverse qft circuit, it doesn’t work.

Comment: Except the outputted result from that circuit is $|10\rangle$, while the expected output is $|01\rangle$. Why does that happen?

Comment: Is it simply dependent on how the endian-ness of the qubits is initialized?

Comment: @JackCeroni In Quirk, the top qubit is the least significant qubit. You might be assuming that the bottom qubit is the least significant?